# BMI Calculator... except BMI won't show up

Tags: javascript

Good evening, everyone :>

I am currently trying to finalize code for a simple BMI calculator. The trouble is that it won't show me a BMI reading when I input my height and weight in my browser. I'm 99% certain that my HTML is solid, it's just the Javascript that seems to be causing problems. Any input I can get on this matter would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>BMI Calculator</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
function calculate() {

var height = document.getElementById("height");
var weight = document.getElementById("weight") * 703;
var denom = Math.pow(height, 2);
var totalbmi = weight/denom;
var bmi = document.getElementById("bmi");
if (isFinite(bmi)) {        
    bmi.innerHTML = totalbmi.toFixed(2); 
}
}
/* ]]> */
</script>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.result {font-weight: bold; }
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form name="details">
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>Height<br />
        (in Inches)</td>
        <td><input type="text" size="3" id="height"            onChange="calculate();"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Weight<br />
        (in Pounds)</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="3" id="weight" onChange="calculate();"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="My BMI" onClick="calculate();"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</table>
<table width="270">
  <tr>
    <td width="104">Your BMI is:</td>
    <td width="154"><input type="text" id="totalbmi"></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging the JS portion?

Answer (score 2):

It's not going to update anything because you have `var bmi = document.getElementById("bmi");`
when it should be `var bmi = document.getElementById("totalbmi");`

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementById()` returns the *HTML node*, not the text inside it. To get the actual weight and height values provided by the user, you should use `document.getElementById("height").value`.

As nathanjosiah pointed out as well, you're referring to a "bmi" node where you probably meant "totalbmi". You're also confusing your 'bmi' and 'totalbmi' *variables*.

```
function calculate() {
  var height = document.getElementById("height").value;
  var weight = document.getElementById("weight").value * 703;
  var denom = Math.pow(height, 2);
  var totalbmi = weight/denom;

  var bmi = document.getElementById("totalbmi");
  if (isFinite(totalbmi)) {        
    bmi.value = totalbmi.toFixed(2); 
  }
}
```

**EDIT**: As others pointed out, you want to set the .value of an input in order to change its displayed content. `<input>` elements are [empty](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.4), so setting one's .innerHTML property doesn't work.

Comment: That got it working. Thanks a bunch! :3

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById()` returns a reference to the (matching) DOM element itself, not to its value. To get/set the value use the `.value` property.

Also you are trying to set the result to a field with id "bmi" when the actual field has the id "totalbmi", and you are trying to set that field's `.innerHTML` (which input elements don't have) instead of its `.value`.

So taking those problems into account:

```
function calculate() {    
    var height = document.getElementById("height").value;
    var weight = document.getElementById("weight").value * 703;
    var denom = Math.pow(height, 2);
    var totalbmi = weight/denom;
    document.getElementById("totalbmi").value =
                 isFinite(totalbmi) ? totalbmi.toFixed(2) : "";
}
```

(Where if the results fail the `isFinite` test I'm setting the output field to an empty string rather than leaving whatever value was in it before.)

Answer (score 0):

In the following line you id is `totalbmi`, but you are using `document.getElementById("bmi");`

```
<input type="text" id="totalbmi">
```

Also, to set the value of the input you would do

`bmi.value = totalbmi.toFixed(2)`

instead of

`bmi.innerHTML = totalbmi.toFixed(2)`